# Possible to turn off predective text in IOS Webview?

Tags: ios, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, webview

I have a hybrid app for all devices and works well for the most part. For IOS, when user have predictive text turn on and when they type on an input box, the input box will shift up and down to match predictive words. Is there a way to programmatically disable the keyboard predictive text from a webview?

Answer (score 0):

Add

> autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"

to the input field. it will disable the checkbox.

[image]